Mocking an Ajax Call
I am new to Sinon mocking and trying to test a function
so my function is something like, save:
function (data) {

    var x = 10;
    var y = [];

    Deferred.when(
        app.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'someurl/x/endpoint',
            success: function (response) {
                console.log("respsonse", response);
                if (!response.error) {
                    y.push(response);
                }
            }
        })

    ).then(function (response1) {
        console.log("Printing 1");
        console.log("response1", response1);
    });

}`

And test is:
  var x= {
        "ID":"10"
    }
    server.respondWith('GET', "someurl/x/endpoint", [
        200,
        { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        JSON.stringify(x)
    ]);
   
    save(data);

The issue is when I am running the test I get
Printing 1
response1 undefined
ERROR: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'response1')
I am using Sinon to mock and maybe going wrong somewhere.
I am trying to mock the GET AJAX call in order to take its response and proceed further.
Please can anyone guide me what's the appropriate way to do so?

I see that you are facing an issue where the response1 is undefined in the callback function passed to the then() method.
One potential issue might be related to the usage of Deferred.when(). In JavaScript, Deferred objects are not built into the language. They are typically implemented using libraries like jQuery or similar. Since you're not explicitly defining Deferred, it might be causing unexpected behavior.
To properly mock the AJAX call and handle its response, you can use Sinon's fakeServer along with promises.

@RavinaSarda  I'm not sure how to do that - could you share an eg of the same?
